# Join Vector3 with BoxBuffer Geometry to make a proper angle join using Threejs

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, scnvector3

I want to create a view which has 6 sides mentioned in the image respectively, we have created all sides and joined respectively but we are stuck at a point when we need to create a side with some angle and need to join with the horizontal side
[image]

We need to create #3 and join with #2 and #4 in such a way that it should be error free we are open for suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, but StackOverflow is not for tutorials or opinion-based questions. If you need to build custom geometry, I recommend you use a 3D editor like [Blender](https://www.blender.org/), then import that into Three.js

Comment: @Marquizzo Thanks for sharing the thoughts but all the sides have dynamic sizes/dimensions but in my case, I need to take input from users ( input box ) then need to create the same shape mentioned in the image with that params.